# Angular 2: how to render dynamically created component after appending to DOM

Tags: typescript, angular

To start with, all the code is available in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zif2jSwCfjkOA0cgIghN?p=preview).

#### Some code

I have a root Angular2 component, like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Angular2 Root Component</h2>
    <div data-dynamic-content></div>
  `,
})
export class App {}
```

The `[data-dynamic-content]` element is a placeholder for components that I will be adding at runtime. These components are dynamic, too, created like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

export function createComponent(selector: string, value: string) {
  @Component({
    selector: selector, 
    template: `<h4>Dynamic Component: {{v}}</h4>`,
  })
  class MyDynamicComponent {
    v = value;
  }

  return MyDynamicComponent;
};
```

Please, keep in mind, that this is an **extremely simplified example**.

#### Problem statement

I want to create different representations of `MyDynamicComponent`, append them somewhere into the `[data-dynamic-content]` element tree, and have them fully-functional.

#### What I've tried

The only thing that worked so far is bootstrapping the freshly created component upon appending to the DOM:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {createComponent} from './my-dynamic.component';

export function addComponentDynamically(selector, value) {
  var dynamicComponent = createComponent(selector, value);

  var container = document.querySelector('[data-dynamic-content]');
  var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.innerHTML = `<${selector}></${selector}>`;
  container.appendChild(wrapper);

  // !! won't work without this line
  bootstrap(dynamicComponent);
};
```

I also played with the `DynamicComponentLoader`. It didn't look like it will fit my needs - the `DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation` requires a `ViewContainerRef` parameter (e.g. you should know beforehand where your component will be located), and I don't have this. As I mentioned before, the `MyDynamicComponent` could be rendered *anywhere* in the `[data-dynamic-content]` element tree, not necessarily in this element itself.

#### Conclusion

While this works, I seriously doubt that such an approach will be scalable (tested in Chrome with 1000 more complex components - memory consumption peaked at around 750 MB, then reduced to ~ 400 MB).

Is there any better way to make this work than calling `bootstrap` over and over again?

Comment: Dynamically added HTML (like `innerHTML`) is just passed along by Angular and not processed at all. There is no way to make Angular instantiate components or directives or resolve bindings for such HTML. I guess https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7596 is the closest you can get.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that's a pretty long thread. Did you try to point to something specific?

Comment: Not really. I don't know what you actually try to accomplish. I think the discussion in the linked issue and the SO link in the issue contain  most of the arguments related to your question.

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular